# expected value of deterministic function

Tags: expected-value

I am intuitively convinced that $E[f(X)] = f(X)$, if $f$ is deterministic, but I cannot derive it using the integral definition of expectation.
Assuming $X \sim unif(0,1)$ I get:
$$
E[f(X)] = \int^{1}_{0}{f(x)p(x)dx} = \int^{1}_{0}{f(x)dx} = \overline{f}
$$
which is not necessarily $f$.

Appreciate any help!

**Edit:** Thank you all, I made a mess with the notations, and somehow my question is not a question anymore

Comment: No, it will happen when $X$ is also deterministic or when $f$ is constant on the range of $X$ but not otherwise. (In these cases the whole quantity $f(X)$ is deterministic.)

Comment: Do you mean that $X$ is deterministic? Otherwise I’m not sure what you mean by a deterministic function.

Comment: @platty maybe I am wrong with the notation and I should use $E[f]$ instead of $E[f(X)]$

Comment: @lan maybe I am wrong with the notation and I should use $E[f]$ instead of $E[f(X)]$

Comment: If you mean that $f$ is a constant function, then this holds (plug in $f(X) = c$ for all $x$ and integrate the constant). Otherwise, it’s not clear what you mean

Comment: @platty I saw [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Derivation) wrote: This, given $y = f + \epsilon$ and $E[\epsilon] = 0$ implies $E[y] = E[f] + E[\epsilon] = E[f] = f$

Comment: This is considering the expectation for a fixed $x$, i.e. $E[f(x)]$, instead of the random variable $E[f(X)]$. So $f(x)$ is constant.

Comment: @platty Aww. Plenty of thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable, so is $f(X)$. Unless $f$ is a degenerate function (i.e. $f(x) = const$), it is not meaningful to compare $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ (which is simply a number, if it exists) to $f(X)$, which is a random variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here your pdf for the deterministic signal is an impulse of infinite amplitude and unit area..then you will get that result.

When you assume a pdf for an RV(taking infinite values) the density function is spread asymptotically..if it is deterministic then variance has to zero which intuitively suggests that it has to be an impulse